# Shadow map in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, shadow-mapping

I've problem with shadow map in OpenGL.
Well, the shadows look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wWm2.png

My vertex shader:

```
 #version 330 core
        layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
        layout(location = 1) in vec3 normal;
        layout(location = 2) in vec2 UV;
        out vec2 oUV;
        out vec3 oNormal;
        out vec4 shadowCoord;
        uniform mat4 MVP;
        uniform mat4 DepthMVP;
        void main(){
            gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vertex, 1);
            shadowCoord = DepthMVP * vec4(vertex, 1);
            oUV = UV;
            oNormal = normal;
        }
```

fragment shader:

```
 #version 330 core
        in vec2 oUV;
        in vec3 oNormal;
        in vec4 shadowCoord;
        out vec3 color;
        uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
        uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;
        void main(){
            float v = 1.0;
            if(texture(shadowMap,
                vec3(shadowCoord.xy, shadowCoord.z /
                shadowCoord.w)) < shadowCoord.z )
            v = 0;
            color = v * texture2D(textureSampler, oUV).rgb*
                vec3(1, 1, 1);
        }
```

and here is how i create frame buffer:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &ld.fb);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ld.fb);
    glGenTextures(1, &ld.dtext);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ld.dtext);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024, 768, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ld.dtext, 0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

What is the problem? Why shadows on objects look so bad?

Comment: That's [Shadow acne](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/)

Comment: Thank you. Now shadow looks much better.